# Парсинг всплывающего окна

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

На сайте https://cinemahall24.ru/seances отображены фильмы, которые идут в кинотеатре. При нажатии на фильм появляется окно, которое нужно распарсить, для этого использую **selenium**, но при вызове **browser.page_source** я получаю html код сайта без этого окна, хотя в консоли браузера html вместе с окошком. Как получить html код сайта вместе с окошком?

Код:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://cinemahall24.ru/seances')
time.sleep(3)

cards = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'widget-overlay')

for card in cards:
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", card)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(browser.page_source)
```

Так тоже не работает

```
for card in cards:
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", card)
    time.sleep(5)
    page = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')
    print(page.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: Что конкретно ты хочешь распарсить, места?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы спарсить popup window нужно на него переключится.
После того как второе окно появилось - получаем дескрипторы всех окон:

```
window_handles = browser.window_handles
```

Далее переключаемся на popup:(Основное окно будет иметь индекс 0, первый popup - следовательно 1)

```
browser.switch_to.window(window_handles[1])
```

Далее скрапим то что нам нужно с этого окна и не забываем переключится на основное окно обратно:

```
browser.switch_to.window(window_handles[0])
```